# Why was my Question edited?

Tags: discussion, question-quality, editing

I recently asked about [Project management software](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/5290/project-management-software-recommendation), and someone changed it? Why is the edit better than the original Question?

**update**: I've changed the Question to be more specific.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was trying to incorporate the actual question into the body (like [Steven D said](https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/355/why-was-my-question-edited/356#356)), and trying to make it less subjective; "What is the most advanced project management FLOSS?" is entirely opinion-based

Comment: I think it can be objective in that __most advanced__ == __has more features__. I don't get what's subjective about that.

Comment: @Tshepang I'm pretty sure "most features" and "most advanced" aren't synonymous

Comment: Actually that's all I meant. What's the difference?

Comment: @Tshepang One really useful feature makes a product more advanced than a dozen totally useless features. Anyway, it's your question; if you don't like the reworded version go ahead and edit it

Comment: I guess 'has more features' is also subjective. Depends on how you specify single feature you may get different results (for example "Writes to standard graphical formats (PNG/JPEG/GIF)" vs. "Writes to PNG"/"Writes to JPEG"/"Writes to GIF").

Answer (score 1):

I think that the editor was trying to ensure that the body of the question was a complete question, without the title.

Personally, I would have edited it a little differently, since I don't like questions that can be answered with a "yes" or a "no" when in fact the asker (I assume) wants a specific recommendation.

Comment: You can edit it, I won't be offended :)

Comment: I agree, questions that look for simple "yes" or "no" answers are a bad fit. Share experiences, details, and examples.